# Accessing Redshift dataset from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

We have a vendor who has their data on a Redshift instance. We have a SQL Server instance which stores all our data. Is there a way that I could 'mount' the Redshift instance as a schema or something so that we are able to access the vendor data by connecting to the remote Redshift instance?

Comment: Anything that can access a Postgresql database would also be able to access Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Imho it's not possible (and it is not possible for any combination of vendors). 
Different DBMS are working with different (proprietary) formats how they are storing data, communicating with other databases is out of scope for them.

For connecting to disparate data sources you could use some ETL tool (Microsoft has SSIS, you can try CloverETL, Talend, Pentaho).

(Or you can try implement some offloading from Redshift to CSV, loading that CSVs to your MSSQL, but again, to do reliably, to keep data reasonably up-to-date etc. you would need some scripting or ETL tool.)